# I don´t know how select HTML Class attribute handled in Javascript toolkit Framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron, javascript-framework

I am using the **Electron** Framework in Javascript called **Xel** toolkit, and I have the following syntax from **main.js**:

```
document.querySelector("menu.selected").className.remove('selected')
```

Having some **Xel** code where **selected** is a pure HTML Class:

```
<x-tab selected class="menu">
```

You know, it is a bad practice something just like this, without type a *Class="name"*. But I don't know how I can catch the **selected** current value. Checking Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish here, but I think this may be of some help.
the following code sample that I am showing you will grab the attribute of checked based on className which I think is what you are ultimately asking for...

[ClickToSeeJsBin](https://jsbin.com/kahona/edit?html,output)

https://jsbin.com/kahona/edit?html,output

```
    function validate() {
    var CurrentSelected = [];
    //Doing the same thing for checkBox selection
    var GetAllCheckBoxNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("someCheckBox");
    var InputNodesSize = GetAllCheckBoxNodes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < InputNodesSize; i++) {
        var CurrentCheckBox = GetAllCheckBoxNodes[i];
        if (CurrentCheckBox.checked) {
            CurrentSelected.push(CurrentCheckBox.value);
        }
    }
    //Doing the same thing for radio selection
    var GetAllRadioNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("someRadio");
    var GetAllRadioNodesLength = GetAllRadioNodes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < GetAllRadioNodesLength; i++) {
        var CurrentRadioNode = GetAllRadioNodes[i];
        if (CurrentRadioNode.checked) {
            CurrentSelected.push(CurrentRadioNode.value);
        }
    }
    //Displaying what is Selected...
    CurrentSelected.forEach(item => { console.log(item); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example `selected` in that context is not a "pure HTML Class". That is an attribute equivalent to `selected="true"` in HTML5. If you want to use `querySelector` to find that element and remove the `selected` attribute with Javascript, you'll need something like this:

```
document.querySelector("menu[selected]").selected = false;
```